# Jquery AJAX (json) cross domain request and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

Seemed to me to be a beaten theme, but i couldn't find the answer. =(
I make jquery ajax requst to 
localhost:666 from localhost:555 application

```
    $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:666/request",
            dataType: 'json',
            timeout: 5000,
            success:...
```

i've got in chrome:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:666/request. Origin http://localhost:555 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

What is the solution of the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697557/accessing-web-service-from-jquery-cross-domain

Answer (score 8):

You can initiate cross-domain request in your webpage by creating either **XMLHttpRequest** object or **XDomainRequest** object. End user's web-browser will request data from the domain's server by sending an "**Origin**" header with the value of origin. If server responds with an "**Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * | Origin**" then we are permitted to access data; otherwise response will be unauthorized request.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    // HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://AllowedDomain.com");
}
```

An article here: [Cross-Origin requests and ASP.NET MVC](http://dashingquill.wordpress.com/2011/08/31/cross-origin-requests-and-asp-net-mvc/)

Answer (score -1):

ajax calls are confined to parent domain only. for this a site on localhost:666 can not open ajax connection to localhost:555 since they belongs to different domain (or origin)

you need to try jsonp: http://www.google.com/search?q=jsonp

Answer (score -2):

Try using dataType: 'jsonp', or $.getJSON function.