# Using Access-Control-Allow-Origin with MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, cross-domain

I'm trying to get simple cross domain call working with a simple HTML with JQuery page and an MVC site on another domain.

I'm basing what I do on this ...

[Setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin in ASP.Net MVC - simplest possible method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290053/setting-access-control-allow-origin-in-asp-net-mvc-simplest-possible-method)

Here's the call in my simple site ...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.get("http://example.com:20874/Home/YourMethod", function (data) {
                alert(data);
            });

        });
    </script>
```

and heres my controller ... the attribute code is just pasted from other question ...

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AllowCrossSiteJson]
    public ActionResult YourMethod()
    {
        return Json(@"{""title"": ""example glossary""}");
    }

}
```

But the calling site errors with ...

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com:20874/Home/YourMethod. Origin http://example.com:90 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Can anyone assist please?

Comment: And where are you setting the necessary HTTP header?

Comment: I believe the [AllowCrossSiteJson] attribute should be doing that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Gave up with the attributes and just did it like this ...

```
    public ActionResult YourMethod()
    {
        HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        return Json(@"{""title"": ""example glossary""}");
    }
```