# Ajax never fires 'success' using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, actionresult

I'm trying to do a simple Ajax call to register a user from a HTML page, the function in the MVC 4 is called and working well, but what it returns never fires the 'success' function in the Ajax call.

If I'm using my browser to manually access the Register() function, it works well and returns the message I want, but not through Ajax

```
function register() {
    var userModel = {
        phoneNumber: "1236663",
        displayname: "yasuuu",
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:13234/home/register",
        data: userModel,
        success: function (response) {
            $('#deleteThisDivButNotItsContent').html(response)
        }
    })
}

    public ActionResult Register(string PhoneNumber, string DisplayName)
    {
        // Some working code here ...

        ViewBag.Message = "Some Message"; // just trying to display simple text

        return View();

        /* tried all of the lines below too */

        //return this.Json("1234");
        //return Json("{ result : true }");
        //return PartialView("ShowResultPartial", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        //CommentSection commentSection = new CommentSection();
        //return PartialView("CommentSection");
        //return PartialView("CommentSection", commentSection);
        //return Json(new { success = true, response = "Saved ok" });
    }
```

I'm using JQuery 2.0.3

Comment: I've searched the internet for hours but couldn't find anything :(

Comment: Which version of jQuery you are using? You should use promise/deferred style with `.done(...)` instead of using `success`

Comment: I think success is obsolete. Try complete instead. [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: With .done(...) it's not working.
But when I use complete like Dmytro said, it does go to the body of .complete(function(data) and when I parse the return parameter using JSON.stringify(data), it turns to {"readyState":4,"status":404,"statusText":"error"}

Comment: Do you get an error in your browser console?

Comment: Jeandre, Nope, this is the message I get in the console:
--
[12:03:15.375] POST http://localhost:13234/home/Register [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 150ms]
// end.

It's weird cause I get 404 in the actual return parameter, what might it be ?

Comment: What is the page url from where you are calling the ajax? Do both the 'page url' and the 'ajax url' belongs to the same domain? i.e. `http://localhost:13234`?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you meant. I'm using "http://localhost:13234/home/Register" in both the browser (which works) and the ajax call (which has this problem). the url is written only once in the ajax code. the ajax call runs Register() , which ends well but the ajax call has this weird problem with the return value..

Comment: I would add `error:    logAjaxError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, this.url)` and set a breakpoint in firebug, always found the issue.

Comment: Solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290053/setting-access-control-allow-origin-in-asp-net-mvc-simplest-possible-method

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this?

```
function register() {
$.post("/home/Register",
       {phoneNumber: "1236663", displayname: "yasuuu"},
       function(data,status,xhr){
            $('#deleteThisDivButNotItsContent').html(data.response);
});
}
```

In the controller

```
return Json(new { success = true, response = "Saved ok" });
```

Comment: Hey,

I've used what you posted, using my browser, doing little modifications to the URL and AllowGet, but still no luck:

  $.post("http://localhost:13234/home/Register", {phoneNumber: "1236663", displayname: "yasuuu"})
  .done(function(data) {
   $('#deleteThisDivButNotItsContent').html(data);
  });

return Json(new { success = true, response = "Saved ok" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Try to go to "localhost:13234/home/Register" using your browser. Can you see a json string or something?

Comment: with the browser, it's working. I'm going to http://localhost:13234/home/register?phonenumber=123&displayname=miko and get the JSON back {"success":true,"response":"Saved ok"}

Comment: Still no luck, the Register() is launched in debug mode, but now nothing is changed in the html.

Comment: with a simple alert() I see the function(data,status,xhr) doesn't get launched., unlike 'complete' which does get launched but with '404'

Answer (score 0):

Let it return `JsonResult` instead of `ActionResult`. How in the world can AJAX interpret an ActionResult view?

Also you send an object to the Register() method but you're receiving two string variables.

Here is an example:

```
function register() {
    var userModel = {
        phoneNumber: "1236663",
        displayName: "yasuuu",
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:13234/Home/Register",
        data: userModel,
        success: function (response) {
            $('#deleteThisDivButNotItsContent').html(response.message)
        }
    });
}

publi class UserModel
{
    public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
}

public JsonResult Register(UserModel userModel)
{
    // Some working code here ...

    return Json(new { message = "Some message here" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Hey,
Same result here.
{"readyState":4,"status":404,"statusText":"error"}

Answer (score 0):

When you type `http://localhost:1234/register` into the browser it is issuing a `GET` request for that URL.  In your javascript, jquery is issuing a `POST` request.  The ajax request is receiving a 404 error because the route is not configured to respond to `POST` requests.

Comment: I've added [HttpPost] before the Register function in the MVC, but it's still not working, is that what you meant ?

Comment: That is what I meant.  Are you looking at the network requests using the browser debug tools?  maybe you can try cUrl (http://curl.haxx.se/)  - the problem is your site is returning an HTTP404 (not found) response to the ajax post.  You just have to figure out why.

Comment: But when I use the browser to call http://localhost:1283/home/register?phonenumber=123&displayname=miko , it works fine.
And when I use Ajax - comes the problem.

Any idea why this could happen ? :\

Comment: try using Ajax to issue a GET request (i.e. $.get("/whatever")), or use CURL to issue POST and GET requests to see if that's the problem.  comparing the ajax call to typing the URL in the browser is not a fair comparison

Comment: Changing to $.get(..) hasn't solved the problem.

I've also tried to run this on Windows 8 with IIS 8, same problem.

CURL looks so complicated :/