# Enable CORS for MVC and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, cors

I have an IONIC/AngularJS application from which I have to call my ASP.NET MVC controller method i.e **Login**. It works with fine with **$http.get()** but when I use **$http.post()** or **$http({method: 'POST'})** it returns an error. The error is (for Chrome):

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource

I have enabled CORS for Server by following the answer to this question:

[CORS in ASP .NET MVC5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218240/cors-in-asp-net-mvc5)

I also included nuget package to enable CORS, but this didn't solve my problem. I also tried adding the following in Angular's POST request:

```
$http({
     method: 'POST',
     url: url,
     headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
     data: _data}).then();
```

but it didn't work either. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Thankx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I ran into another issue after I successfully hit my post method. The error i received was:

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://url  Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404". 

So i included the following with my post requests:

$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};

Now it hits my post method, but my method is returning an error with null data. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your WebApiConfig

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Comment: Do you need to register that somewhere? I imagine that just creating the variable doesn't do anything after it goes out of scope.