# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: & Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, cors, cross-domain

perhaps this question seems duplicate, but I have my own scenario, `ASP.NET MVC` application, when I click on check-out  it throws following error.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://servicelink?order=%5Bobject%20Object%5D.
>   (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

[image]

Comment: You need to add CORS headers to the response generated from your ASP code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i have gone through several articles but I couldn't understand, how to add and where to add those headers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218240/cors-in-asp-net-mvc5

Comment: I have no access to web service

Comment: In that case you cannot make a request to it through JS code. You will have to make the request on the server

Comment: cannot I do this through this available script ?

Comment: No. Cross domain requests are blocked for security reasons, unless expressly allowed by the receiving domain through the CORS header. As the domain you're calling doesn't have these headers, you cannot call it through JS code

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I found the web.config, see edit in question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will not be able to access this service from javascript because you are on domain **aaa.com** and the service you are trying to access is on domain **bbb.com**.This is a security feature implemented by browsers called [Same Origin Policy.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Specifying `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>` or enabling CORS from your side will not accomplish anything.You need to contact Telemo solutions and **ask them** to allow requests coming from your server\domain to call their service through javascript.This is ofcourse very unlikely to happen unless they are your business partner or you have some sort of agreement with them so what you will probably have to do is call their service methods from the C# code.

You can change your javascript to call a server side action\web method in your code behind and in the code behind write C# code to call the Telemo solutions methods:

[image: Using a proxy to avoid same origin policy violations]

Comment: also showing in above **Inspect element** image attached in question