# Enable CORS In MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to access *localhost:5002/api/login* through *localhost:9000*.

I have tried almost all the solutions available online.
But I keep getting the following error.

How to present the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on the requested resource.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load ***localhost:5002/api/login***. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin ***'localhost:9000'*** is therefore not allowed access.

I have tried adding this to the Web.config

> ```
> <httpProtocol>
>   <customHeaders>
>     <clear />
>     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
>   </customHeaders>
> </httpProtocol>
> ```

And In the server side StartUp.cs File I have added the following as well

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

```
    {  
        services.AddCors(options =>

        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IUowProvider uowProvider)

```
    {
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Comment: is this Web API 2?

Comment: It would be helpful if you briefly enumerate what you have tried.

Comment: Its not Web API 2. We are using MVC Controllers.

Answer (score 2):

> Step I:
>   please keep the below code in webconfig and within  part:

```
<httpProtocol>
<customHeaders>
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
 OPTIONS" />
</customHeaders>
```

> Step II:
>   We have added Application_BeginRequest method in Global.asax class. Generally, this method checks Header's all keys. If it contains with "Origin" and Request HttpMethod is "OPTIONS", then ends all currently buffered output to the client

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            Response.Flush();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've tried dozens of things to enable Cors in my MVC application, and adding this code to the Application_BeginRequest is what finally solved it for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Normally you should be able to add the CORS configuration to either your WebAPI configuration or web.config.

For the WebAPI configuration you should specify the following:

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
```

In the `web.config` it should look like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
<system.webServer>
```

Of course, this allows *all* origins, so you have to change it to `localhost:9000` in your situation. Keep in mind, different ports are different origins, so specifying only `localhost` isn't sufficient, the port should be added also!

Comment: Which means i have to specifically add the localhost:9000 as well?

Comment: Yes, in your case it could look like `app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:9000"));` or `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:9000" />`, instead of the `*` (asterisk). A nice article about it can be found over here on the MS documentation site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors

Comment: I still cant seem to get it fixed. Plus we do not have WebAPI configurations. We are using MVC controllers.

Comment: This is more useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218240/cors-in-asp-net-mvc5