# The result of json is empty when calling from cordova + angular.js

Tags: json, angularjs, cordova

I am new to angular.js

I am trying to get json data as described in samples, as

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var module = angular.module('app', ['onsen']);

module.controller('GroupController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost/dinner/hOME/Categories")
    .success(function (response) { $scope.categories = response; })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { alert(status); });
    });

});
```

but code will go through error method with status=0, data =null

while when I open the link `http://localhost/dinner/hOME/Categories` in my browser there is response.

What is my mistake?

### ServerSide Code (ASP.net MVC 3)

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Categories()
{
    IRecipeCategoryService rcSrv = ServiceFactory.Create<IRecipeCategoryService>();
    var categoryList = rcSrv.FetchAll().Select(i => new {i.ID , i.Title }).OrderBy(j => j.Title).ToList();
    return Json( categoryList
                    , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

### Update (based on Sujata Chanda comments )

I have add these codes for CORS problem but it didn't help

```
module.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}
]);
```

### Solution

from  Christopher Marshall hint I made changes on server side based on this link
[Setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin in ASP.Net MVC - simplest possible method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290053/setting-access-control-allow-origin-in-asp-net-mvc-simplest-possible-method)
On server application adding this `ActionFilter`

```
public class AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

then tagging my action as below

```
[AllowCrossSiteJson]
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Categories()
{
    IRecipeCategoryService rcSrv = ServiceFactory.Create<IRecipeCategoryService>();
    var categoryList = rcSrv.FetchAll().Select(i => new {i.ID , i.Title }).OrderBy(j => j.Title).ToList();
    return Json( categoryList
                    , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Comment: Status 0 comes for CORS problem. Try to resolve that.

Comment: Is that endpoint set up to return your json? If it's just a file you can use the `get` request directly on the file. `http://localhost/dinner/hOME/Categorie.json`

Comment: try 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost remember it's only work in emulator not in device

Comment: @shammon 10.0.2.2 didn't work at all. and with 127.0.0.1 same problem exists

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall I have updated my question and I have added server side code, do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Did you tested in device or emulator

Comment: @shammon on Chrome Ripple

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall Thanks for your hint, I found the solution

Comment: CORS issue is still happening.run the app in emulators like bluestack or genymotion it should work