# Add 'access-control-allow-origin' response to options preflight request in Asp.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cors, asp.net-core

I'm getting the following error in Chrome:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseCors(policy => policy
       .WithOrigins("http://localhost:9000")
       .AllowAnyMethod()
       .WithHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Content-Type, x-xsrf-token, Authorization")
       .AllowCredentials());

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

According to chrome there is not a single header being added to the response.

What is the correct way to add the `access-control-allow-origin` header to a options response in Asp.NET 5?

Comment: This is the bleeding edge, so I haven't had much time to play with it, but what you're doing doesn't seem to gibe with the official documentation: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/cors.html Not saying it's incorrect, but where did you find your guidance? I wouldn't have thought you are required to explicitly set a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header given that you are obviously setting a CORS policy.

Comment: I really don't remember the app.UseCors block I put in a long time ago when I had to get my standard GET requests for the page working. (They don't work without it). However now that I have got to more complex requests, the browser is sending a preflight request which this bit of code doesn't work for.

Comment: Also I will point out that the documentation there is actually outdated (although the latest).

Comment: Why don't you use `.AllowAnyHeader();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense but as @Sirwan suggested, using `.AllowAnyHeader()` set the access on the options response...

Answer (score 5):

**Consider that** Google Chrome has [an issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743) which does not support *localhost* to go through the *Access-Control-Allow-Origin*.

In your code, you have enabled CORS with the `AddCors` and `UseCors` methods in `Configure` method, please make sure you've followed the instructions available in [Specifying a CORS Policy](http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.org/projects/mvc/en/latest/security/cors-policy.html) (*which is used in `ConfigureServices` method*) and [How to enable CORS in ASP.NET 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31942128/1743997)

You can also simply write an [Action Filter for plain Asp.net MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6290385/1743997).

### Types of CORS'

1. `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` : use it to enable the CORS request
   ONLY for the Web APIs.
2. `Microsoft.AspNet.Cors` : Use it to enable CORS for MVC controllers.
3. `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` : Use it to enable CORS for all cross-origins
   requests coming to your site, for example, when you you want to
   enable CORS for both Web API and SignalR.

Answer (score 0):

to overcome preflight issue add same name method as `[httpoption]` in your API and return success from there, now just run your web/client application you will hit the same  method twice very first time httpoption method will hit and then your original

Answer (score 0):

Place this in the configure section in the `startup.cs` file:

```
app.UseCors (x => x.AllowAnyOrigin ().AllowAnyMethod ().AllowAnyHeader ());
```