# How to enable cross origin requests in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cors

I am trying to create a web application which works with cross-origin requests (CORS) in MVC 5. I have tried everything without any result.

**With an attribute**

```
public class AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

**With EnableCors attribute**

```
 [EnableCors("*")]
```

Nothing works I'm starting to think that it is impossible

Comment: Have you read the samples: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: I found the solution in this post : https://forums.asp.net/post/5795304.aspx

Answer (score -6, accepted):

To enable cross-origin requests, add the `[EnableCors]` attribute to your Web API controller or controller method:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://systematixindia.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
   // Controller method`enter code here`s not shown...
}
```

[Read More](http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html)

Comment: Your solution is for Web Api, read the title of question! It doesn't work for MVC.

Comment: this code can be added for Global configuration public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // To do : Set at global place  ex web.config 
            
            EnableCorsAttribute corsConfig = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET,POST");
            // Web API configuration and services
            config.EnableCors(corsConfig);

Comment: @OmarIsaid That class (WebAPIConfig.cs) is not there in MVC projects

Answer (score 66):

Add the configuration setting in your web.config file to set the value for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in `customHeaders` like this -

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You would like to visit [this](http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html) and [this](http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html) for more details and some other options.

Comment: it is showing the result like this: "from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8787' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."

Comment: In my case, I needed to set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" with "*" as indicated in this answer, but.... I also needed to add this to my angularjs clientside `$http` call: `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'}`

Answer (score 60):

What I think is the most convenient is to create your own class like this :

[image]

with the following code in it :

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class AllowCrossSiteAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

After this it's let you use this decorator on a **method** or on the whole **controller**

[image]
[image]

You should be able to see that in your **response header** after this procedure

[image]

Thank's to this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6290385/4995051)

Comment: You should also include `filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Vary", "Origin");`

Comment: but i got error as "EventSource's response has a MIME type ("application/json") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection"

Answer (score 1):

I've had success using the OWIN CORS implementation (nuget Microsoft.Owin.Cors) to enable Cors for MVC Controllers and Owin middleware, in addition to ApiControllers.  Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors (using `config.EnableCors()` and the `[EnableCors]` attribute) only seems to work with ApiControllers.

See http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-webapi-cors for sample code.

Comment: Best answer if you don't want to use the wildcard '*'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add it into "OnAuthentication" step or add config into your web config. You can try my code :) it works

```
 public class AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use below code to allow cross-origin request

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
        {
     context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" , "*");
}
```

Comment: Where does this code go?

Comment: inside global.asax file

Answer (score -2):

Enabling CORS in mvc 5(core) first need to add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors` package to your project. Then configure `startup.cs` like this for all website

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddMvc();
     //Add Cors support to the service
     services.AddCors();

     var policy = new Microsoft.AspNet.Cors.Core.CorsPolicy();

     policy.Headers.Add("*");    
     policy.Methods.Add("*");          
     policy.Origins.Add("*");
     policy.SupportsCredentials = true;

     services.ConfigureCors(x=>x.AddPolicy("AllPolicy", policy));

 }


 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment  env)
 {
     // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

     app.UseStaticFiles();
     //Use the new policy globally
     app.UseCors("AllPolicy");
     // Add MVC to the request pipeline.
     app.UseMvc();
 }
```

and then also you can use like this

```
[EnableCors("AllPolicy")]
```

Details [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/cors.html)

Comment: An error: EnableCors doesn't take origins parameter

Comment: which version of asp.net mvc you are using ?

Comment: ohh for 5 things are different, check out the link in my update

Comment: check update, I have added for mvc 5

Comment: This solution is for .net core mvc, not suitable for mvc 5 (.net framework)