# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngOriginalError' of undefined at getOriginalError - when httpClient returned string

Tags: angular

When I tried to call an API using [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http#httpclient) which returns a string, subscribe method's error handler was invoked.

Front End Code :

```
this.httpClient.get<string>(`${this.baseUrl}/account/getname`).subscribe(
      (accountName)=> console.log(accountName),
      () => console.log("Failure")
    );
```

Backend Code in controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetName()
{               
   return "Sample Account Name";
 }
```

The front end code will log "`Failure`" to the console.

If the error notification method is removed from `subscribe()`, following error occurs

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngOriginalError' of
>   undefined  at getOriginalError

Comment: I think cors error has occurred when contacting the asp.net mvc application.Please refer to this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40079214/how-to-enable-cross-origin-requests-in-asp-net-mvc/40079857

Answer (score 8):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngOriginalError' of undefined at getOriginalError

This happens because response from the server side goes as an error and there is no handler for error. I guess, the solution is always handle error when making http request by `HttpClient`:

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

makeHttpRequest(url): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient.get(url)
   .pipe(
     catchError(err => console.log(err))
   );
}

makeHttpRequest(`${this.baseUrl}/account/getname`).subscribe(
  (accountName) => console.log(accountName);
);
```

Comment: yes, that correct. But the reason for error was not specifying responsetype of httpclient

Answer (score 1):

Since the default response type of HttpClient is **JSON**, it expected the response object to be a json value.

But our response was a **string**.
This was the reason behind the error.

When an API returns non JSON data, we need to specify it using `responseType` option in the `get` request.

There are different options like '`blob`','`text`','`arraybuffer`','`json`'

For the above case, if we do not specify the get call's type prameter as string (`get<string>`), we just need to set responseType as `{responseType : 'text'}`

```
return this.httpClient.get(`${this.baseUrl}/account/getname`, 
       {responseType : 'text' }).subscribe(
             (data)=> console.log(data),
             () => console.log("Failure")
       );
```

But if we specify the get call's type prameter as string, there will be an error

> Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'

To avoid that we need to modify the `requestType` option to `{responseType : 'text' as 'json'}`

```
 return this.httpClient.get<string>(`${this.baseUrl}/account/getname`, 
        {responseType : 'text' as 'json'}).subscribe(
             (data)=> console.log(data),
             () => console.log("Failure")
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your response type in your http method(post/get/put) because its by default json type but some time your response has blob or text then this type of error occurs.

**responseType?: 'arraybuffer'|'blob'|'json'|'text'** in angular lib