# how to set content type to multipart/form-data in angular 7

Tags: angular, multipartform-data

I know this type of question has asked several times in here and some forums.

What i'm trying to do is upload a file to my server. Down below is my first attempt to set headers to `multipart/form-data`. Below is my service for the file upload.

```
uploadNewFile (formData): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set('Content-Type', undefined);
    return this.http.post(environment.baseURL+'api/v1/company/someFileUpload' , formData, {headers: headers})
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.formatErrors)
      );
  }
```

But when i do this, i'm getting this error.

> Error: Multipart: Boundary not found

But then after seeing this question([Send multipart/form-data files with angular using $http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722093/send-multipart-form-data-files-with-angular-using-http)) i changed my header to this.

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set('Content-Type', undefined)
```

But when I changed it like that, I am getting this error.

[image]

But when i check an aswer for that error it says that i need to add a handler in here ([Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngOriginalError' of undefined at getOriginalError - when httpClient returned string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55019512/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-ngoriginalerror-of-undefined-at-getor))

But i have a handler for my service. Service is pasted in below.

```
uploadNewFile (formData): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set('Content-Type', undefined);
    return this.http.post(environment.baseURL+'someFileUpload' , formData, {headers: headers})
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.formatErrors)
      );
  }
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: I don't see you're passing the headers to the post. In the other hand I think you need to do this instead `headers = headers.set('Content-Type', <header>);`

Comment: oh sorry, my bad. I have copied it without the header part. I tried to upload without hears too. But it didn't work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check for interceptors, because you may have set cintent type for application json in the interceptors