# Add HttpHeader to Static File to solve "Script Error"

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, cors, signalr

I have been banging my head against the wall trying to fix this issue for a week. Hopefully someone can see something I am missing.

I have two projects: `localhost:A` (Web-Api) hosts a js file and `localhost:B` (.NET MVC) uses that js file. When attempting to capture an error in the js file and send it to `localhost:A` I get a cryptic `Script Error` message instead of the actual error.

A quick google search tells me this is an security measure that prevents `localhost:A` from gathering information about the client. To solve this I need to do two things:

1. add `crossorigin='anonymous'` the the `localhost:B`'s reference to the js file
2. add the HttpHeader `Access-Control-Allow-Origin="*"` to the js file response.

I have found several ways to do 2. on Web-Api, but none seem to work.

I have tried adding the header in the Web.config file like this:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
  </customHeaders>
<httpProtocol>
```

I have tried adding the header in the Global.asax.cs file like this:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(corsAttr);

    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I have tried adding the header in the Startup.cs file like this:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    //app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);<--and here
    app.Map("/signalr", map =>
    {
        map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
        {
            EnableDetailedErrors = true
        };
        map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
    });
}
```

HTTP and SignalR transmissions are occurring with the header, but the files that are being fetched are missing the header.

What am I missing?

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of the current Request and Response headers: 
[image]

EDIT 2: If I remove the code in startup.cs, and add the code in web.config, I start getting the header, but also start getting a 404 response looking for signalr/hubs. Having the code in startup.cs and the webconfig gives me this error: `The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.`

Comment: Do you see the browser making a OPTIONS request? If yes what is the response. Can you check what is happening in the networking tab?

Comment: @TarunLalwani See my edit.

Comment: Are you hosting in IIS? If so, might well be that IIS is handling the request for the static resource, rather than your application code. This thread goes into some more detail that may help you diagnose this, and some options available to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458444/enabling-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-iis7.

Comment: @DylanMorley I already had `<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>` in my web.config and the Application_BeginRequest never seems to come across the OPTIONS HttpMethod

Comment: have you tried `Content-type: application/javascript`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was never able to find a solution for this. I ended up creating a CDN for the js/css files which allowed me to set the custom Headers in the web.config while keeping the signalr configuration in another project.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly then you are requesting ***localhost:B*** from browser and the page that **site B** sends in response loads some javascript files from **site A**.

If the above understanding is correct and you are getting an cross origin request error then you are getting this error because the **site A** is not allowing **site B** to request resources. For that you will have to make changes in **site A** to allow CORS requests from **site B**. Depending on the server side language you are using you can google how to allow cors request. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40080162/2313097) is an example for .net Web API

**Edit**
I an not .NET developer but just noticed mistake in your web.config. It was not telling which methods to allow, so I searched on the internet and found that this is the right way to do it using web.config:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:B"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
<httpProtocol>
```

Comment: I am well aware that I need siteA to allow CORS request from siteB. See EDIT 2 for more clarification.

Comment: Got it... See the Edit in my answer... let me know if it works... :)