# Consume string returned by REST API (C#) with Vue.js and Axios

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, vue.js, axios

I've created and deployed an API on Azure. My test method returns a string with the value "working".
The API can be tested here : https://audaciaballapi20200911031401.azurewebsites.net/Test

I would like to show "working" inside an alert box using javascript (Vue.js). How can this be done?

This is the method of my API :

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public string Test()
{
    return "working";
}
```

This is the code I'm using in my vue :

```
<template>
    <div class="home">
        <router-link to="/gameType" tag="button">New Game</router-link>
        <br /><br/>
        <router-link to="/gameHistory" tag="button">Game History</router-link>
        <br /><br />
        <router-link to="/addPlayer" tag="button">Create Player</router-link>
        <router-link to="/addTeam" tag="button">Create Team</router-link>
        <div id="app"></div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import axios from 'axios';

async function getTest() {
    const response = await axios ({
        url: "https://audaciaballapi20200911101217.azurewebsites.net/Test",
        method: "get"
    })

    alert(response.data);
}

getTest()

</script>
```

**Problem** : no alert box pops up

**Expected behavior** : alert box pops up with "working" as text

**EDIT : FIGURED IT OUT**
Following the advice from the comment below, I've followed this tutorial : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

I've also modified my code in the BE as follows :

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("test")]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Test()
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent("working")
            };
        }
```

Now, I can show the response data in my FE. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the call, the problem is not on the **FE** side but on the **BE** as the problem is on the **CORS** side,

link to read up on CORS, what it is and how it works https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors

enable cors on .net core => [How to enable CORS in ASP.net Core WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379560/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core-webapi)

enable cors on .net framework => [How to enable cross origin requests in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40079214/how-to-enable-cross-origin-requests-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Thanks! I believe the problem was indeed in the backend. I followed this tutorial : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api and modified my code, I'll post my answer above. Cheers

Comment: happy to help you :D if it work please mark this answer as correct