# EnableCors working with ApiController but not with Controller .NET Framework 4.7.2

Tags: c#, .net, cross-domain

In my project I have 2 type of controllers

1. public class BaseApiController : ApiController
2. public class BaseController : Controller

From Angular I am able to access APIControllers but not able to access Controllers. Getting error for Cross-Origin Request Blocked.
Although Cross-Origin is enabled as I can access APIControllers.

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(
            origins: "*",
            headers: "*",
            methods: "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Any idea what else settings are required to access Controllers.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried to add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in the web.config?

Comment: Are the OPTIONS requests succeeding?

Comment: @Giox, Yes I have tried that too, but not working at all even APIController stop working.

Comment: @CaiusJard, Yes with APIControllers OPTIONS request are returning 200, but not with Controller

Answer (score 1):

I got solution as suggest by @Fitch from this URL.
[How to enable cross origin requests in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40079214/how-to-enable-cross-origin-requests-in-asp-net-mvc/40079857)

Create a class as below

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class AllowCrossSiteAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

And add attribute like below.

```
    [Helpers.AllowCrossSite]
    public JsonResult GetDetails()
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            name = "",
            address = "",
            // ... more properties
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: @CaiusJard, No those extra spaces should not be there, looks like something went wrong when posting answer, I have corrected them.