# How to enable cross origin requests in ASP.NET MVC 4 on POST using Angular 2

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-mvc-4, cors

I'm trying to make a POST request with CORS.

I've a class that adds the correct response header on my methods inside my controller

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class AllowCrossSiteAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

and I use it like this

```
[AllowCrossSite]
public ActionResult GetReportParameters(string IdRapport)
```

and I get the expected result [image]

**But the problem is when I'm trying to make a POST request with a custom header to pass this specific content type**

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
```

I'm actually getting these Response headers

[image]

So it's like nothing is done about the header even if I'm correctly going in my attribute class.

**Here is my front side in Angular 2** service

```
const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });
const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers , withCredentials: true });

const mock = {
  name: 'TitreRegroupement1',
  visible: false,
  type: 'System.String',
  value: 'Test'
};

// tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
const body = JSON.stringify({ idRapport: '00392024-d171-4f39-9c5c-97a51f53fd54', filtre: '', exportFormat: '', parameters: data });

return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/ReportingViewer/ExportReport', body, options)
  .map((response: Response) => {
      return this.extractSingleData(response, Parameters);
  })
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

By using postman there is no problem to declare, the whole thing travel correctly I can access my parameters from the method inside the controller with no problem.

Comment: Do not forget ID is a keyword :
{controller}/{action}/{id}
client side javascript:
 $http.get("../controller/action/" + ID).then(function (r) {
                $scope.item = r.data;
            }); 
server side C#.net:
 public JsonResult action(int ID){...}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found how to make it work. First I apply what proposed me **sideshowbarker**

> ```
> if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin", StringComparer.OridinalIgnoreCase) &&
>     Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS") {
>     Response.Flush();
> }
> ```

and I was missing something in my Headers, I was doing "*" all the way but finally with these parameters it worked

```
filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

for those who are interested in the final form of my class here it is

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Via.Client.WebMvc
{
    public class AllowCrossSiteAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {    
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious why do you prefer `OnActionExecuting` over `OnActionExecuted` as you won't have to `Flush()` if the latter was chosen ..

Answer (score 4):

Your frontend JavaScript code is triggering your browser to do a CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

You need to change the server-side code to handle that `OPTIONS` request, by adding, for example:

```
if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin", StringComparer.OridinalIgnoreCase) &&
    Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS") {
    Response.Flush();
}
```

Or see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basp.net-mvc%5D+%5Bcors%5D+options for many other related answers.

Answer (score 1):

The code that you have tried is all good. This should be work but in your case this is not working.

I have a reference for you about it you have to check it out

[**Setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin in ASP.Net MVC - simplest possible method**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290053/setting-access-control-allow-origin-in-asp-net-mvc-simplest-possible-method)