# POST Method not allowed in ASP.NET MVC (using CORS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cors

I have configured Web.Config in web.Server element.

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:xxxxx" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="content-type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />
      </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

When it comes GET Request all data are retrieved.

When I want to POST new element in request, I get error 405 method not allowed.
What can be the reason?

Request example:
General:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:xxxxx/api/company
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
```

Response Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:yyyyy
Allow:GET,POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:76
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Request headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:xxxxx
Origin:http://localhost:yyyyy
Referer:http://localhost:yyyyy/ddddd/zzzzzz
```

Comment: POST your POST method/endpoint :)

Comment: @TezWingfield updated request example.

Comment: Thank you, can you add your post method? So we can rule any code issues.

Comment: I use syncfusion javascript that why.

Comment: @mjwills Request URL:http://localhost:xxxxx/api/company. CORS is only in web.config like I presented.

Comment: What is the URL of the page that this JS is running in? What is the URL of the page it is failing to POST to?

Comment: http://localhost:yyyyy/admin/company

Comment: I asked two questions. What is the answer to the first question? What is the answer to the second question? Also, please don't use xxxxx and yyyyy - please put the actual values.

Comment: Where is your controller code? Are you POSTing to the correct/convention/annotated `action`?

Comment: The `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` & `Access-Control-Request-Method` headers shown in the question indicate the `405` you’re getting isn’t for the `POST` from your code but is instead for the CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request the browser (automatically on its own) sends before even trying your `POST`.

The solution is to configure handling for `OPTIONS` requests on the backend of the server your frontend code’s sending the request to.

See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43912655/how-to-enable-cross-origin-requests-in-asp-net-mvc-4-on-post-using-angular-2/43913773#43913773

Answer (score 0):

I believe the for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin should "*". Then it might work.

Comment: The same result.