# Asp.net MVC API: CORS preflight channel did not succeed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, methods, cors, cross-domain

I am using `Asp.net MVC Web API` for my website. I added below lines in `web.config` to prevent `Cors` issue. It is working fine for `GET` method but showing an error for all other request methods.
How do I solve this issue?
`<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type,Accept"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding `EnableCorsAttribute` in `WebApiConfig`.
Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code or go through this link : [Access-Control-Allow-Origin in ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290053/setting-access-control-allow-origin-in-asp-net-mvc-simplest-possible-method)

Put all domains that have access to your web server in origin and in headers put all possible headers.

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-AspNet-Version,X-Powered-By,Date,Server,Accept,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Cache-Control,Connection,Content-Length,Content-Type,Host,Origin,Pragma,Referer,User-Agent" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1000" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a full beginner but:

initial Web.config

```
...      
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
...
```

I added `<customHeaders>` and deleted `<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>`.

final Web.config

```
...        
<system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
          <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
          <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
        <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:3000" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-AspNet-Version,X-Powered-By,Date,Server,Accept,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Cache-Control,Connection,Content-Length,Content-Type,Host,Origin,Pragma,Referer,User-Agent" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1000" />
          </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
      </system.webServer>
...
```

It worked for me.