# Disable CORS in ASP.NET MVC framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I developped an ASP.NET MVC web site. In this site I have some url, for example, `site.com/url/` where I can send post request to and get some response.

How can I disable getting results from this url for requests from different domains and allow getting results only for requests from domain `site.com`?

I read about CORS but I don't know whether it can be used in my case.

Answer (score -2):

```
    builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                          policy  =>
                          {
                              policy.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                                                  "http://www.contoso.com");
                          });
    });

...
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseAuthorization();
```

[link to article](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: This code for .net core, but I use .net framework. How can I do the same in .net framework?

Comment: @AntonMakarov in ASP.NET try to use EnableCors attibute https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api or setup cors in you hosting(IIS, ngings ...)

Comment: Thanks. This link describes web api in .net framework, but I use .net framework mvc. Will it work in my case?

Comment: Try) I think Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors must work in ,net frameworks.

Comment: Clear code without any modules and packages - use custom action filter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290053/setting-access-control-allow-origin-in-asp-net-mvc-simplest-possible-method