# RESTful API url calling from a different domain

Tags: cordova, restful-url

I have the following restful api ajax call:

```
   $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",

                    url: "https://website.com/a/login",

                    data: data,

                    dataType: "json"

                })....
```

where data is:

```
data["login"]="username";
data["pass"]="1234";
```

the problem is that this code only works when run from my domain. But when I put this code to run externally, for example from jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/
or from phonegap. This no longer works, and returns me with nothing.

How would I remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because of Cross-domain Ajax calls. Please take a look at following threads for more information:

- [Cross-Domain Requests with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638773/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery)
- [jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)
- [Jquery AJAX (json) cross domain request and ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968682/jquery-ajax-json-cross-domain-request-and-asp-net-mvc)

I hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

This would work on PhoneGap but you would need to add your domain to whitelist. 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html