# Access Wsdl web service client side GWT

Tags: gwt, soap, wsdl, client-side, wsdl2java

I'm working in an GWT 2.4 project. I want to access to a SOAP service. I used wsdl2java to generate classes of the service (servicestub, servicelocator, ...). But this code is server side. How can I do to access the service on the client-side?

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in `Calling Cross Domain Web Services in AJAX`. You can read answer on this question: [Accessing web Service from jQuery - cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697557/accessing-web-service-from-jquery-cross-domain). But you can call server method using [RPC](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.1/tutorial/RPC). And then server get data from SOAP and return to client.

Comment: Thanks but this is about calling a web service using GWT not Ajax or JQuery. The RPC solution should maybe work, but it's tedious.

Comment: Sorry, geeko, GWT is Javascript, at least it is after it has been compiled. GWT can do nothing that JavaScript can't also do.

Answer (score 0):

Its really tricky to do that (I'm even not sure if its possible) and I would prefer to wrap the SOAP call into a server side service and call that from you client.

Comment: I thought about it. But the problem is my requests and responses send the objects generated by wsdl2java. So to be able to use the service I must have those objects on the client-side.Wrapping the soap call will include making a proxy for each of the objects. And I have over 30 objects. It's really tedious. <br>

Comment: Thats right. You have to create DTOs an map your soap objects from and to those DTOs.