# Make post webservices call with jquery through cross domain XML

Tags: c#, web-services, jquery-mobile, cross-domain

I'm trying to make webservices call from a jQuery mobile website on an ASP.NET base.
The webservices take post parameter and return an XML.
I cannot change the webservice side.

I'm facing the cross domain problem, and from my understanding, I need to use a proxy.

I'm thinking of using a generic handler but I don't know how to do that.

My services methods looks like that:

```
https://myserver.com/WCF/Info.svc/MyMehod1
https://myserver.com/WCF/Info.svc/MyMehod2
```

And take Post parameters

What would be a good way to do that in c#?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work.

for those who have the same problem,

on the client side, I have used a generic handler to do the webservice call and expose the result.

Handler sample:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string method = context.Request.QueryString["method"].ToString().ToLower();

    if (method == "MyMethod1")
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write(CallWebService(method, param));
        context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    }
    else if (method == "MyMethod2")
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        string param = "myparam";
        context.Response.Write(CallWebService(method, param));
        context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    }
    else
    {
    //context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    //context.Response.Write("Hello World");
    }


}

private string CallWebService(string method, string param)
{
    string ServeurURL = "https://myserver.com"; 

    System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(ServeurURL + method);
    req.Method = "POST";

    byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(param);
    req.ContentType = "text/xml";
    req.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    System.IO.Stream reqstream = req.GetRequestStream();
    reqstream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    reqstream.Close();

    System.Net.WebResponse wResponse = req.GetResponse();
    reqstream = wResponse.GetResponseStream();
    System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(reqstream);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

    return responseFromServer;
}
```

jQuery/Ajax call:

```
jQuery(function() {
        $('#btn1').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "MyHandler.ashx",
                data: "method=MyMethod1",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#display').html("<h1>" + data.toString() + "</h1>");
                }
            });
        });
        $('#btn2').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "MyHandler.ashx",
                data: "method=MyMethod2",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#display').html("<h1>" + data.toString() + "</h1>");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

And now it's working :)

Comment: Hey @Distwo, glad that worked out for you. Just a tip: it's probably better etiquette in cases like this to to update your question with the answer you chose, rather than unaccept the answer.

Comment: I thought I could mark both as accepted answered, your being the logic, and mine being the associated code, but it removed the first one... :(

Answer (score 2):

Check this question out: [Accessing web Service from jQuery - cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697557/accessing-web-service-from-jquery-cross-domain)

As an alternative, you could also create an HttpHandler that you invoke with jQuery Ajax. The handler can then call the web service and write the output to the Http response.

Comment: I used the httpHandler alternative and it worked.
I will post my code as soon as stackoverflow allow me, for those who will face the same problem ;)