# Read txt file using Jquery on phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova

I am trying to read .txt file using jquery from phonegap index file, but the jquery function returns nothing

Here is my code:

```
jQuery.get('http://gridberry.com/uploaded_files/E1BDA03F-3F9A-45E7-B16D-78F68C21DCD8.txt', function(data) {
   alert(data);
});
```

You can check the link of the txt file; it has data. What is the problem?

Comment: You're likely running into the same origin policy. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697557/accessing-web-service-from-jquery-cross-domain

Comment: I got 404 when I tried opening the text file in the browser. Also did you try running this in the simulator. You will not face cross-origin issues in the simulator so this should work. But please check the link of the file first.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use ajax requests to access data from a different domain. An easy workaround to this is make a PHP script that downloads the contents from that URL like so.

```
echo file_get_contents('http://gridberry.com/uploaded_files/E1BDA03F-3F9A-45E7-B16D-78F68C21DCD8.txt');
```

And `.get()` the script on your server.

Comment: I cant write php in phonegap files

Comment: surely you can make ajax request to different domains. is called [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).

Answer (score 2):

Trying your code in JSfiddle gave me this error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://gridberry.com/uploaded_files/E1BDA03F-3F9A-45E7-B16D-78F68C21DCD8.txt. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

This is a classic cross-domain problem... you can't call an url outside your domain that way.

Comment: Can you use jsonp format instead of plain text? Ajax call using jsonp datatype is one of the way that allow to overcome cross-domain issue (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Answer (score 1):

its probably a cross domain call,hence its failing,
you can do either of 2 things.
1.) Try to do Jsonp to make this call so that you can get the cross domain call working.

2)put a script tag with source as your url and read the script tag inner content in your javascript

Answer (score 0):

try `jQuery('#where_it_displays').load(file_url_here);`

[(jQuery doc)](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: not working for me .. maybe there is something missing in the question that I am trying to load the txt file from phonegap www files?

Comment: Did you put your load function inside a jQuery('document').ready() function?